# When is asking for a recommendation on-topic?

Tags: discussion, flags, recommendation-questions

I flagged this question as off-topic on the grounds it was asking for a recommendation:

[Is there a term to define source control management software that makes full versions of changes, and not deltas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013413/what-source-control-management-softwares-will-fully-backup-old-versions)

My flag has been disputed. Can anyone explain why?

EDIT

I understand the difference between ‘declined’ and ‘disputed’. So, my question is not a duplicate as suggested. My question is how can a question that is overtly asking for a recommendation not result in a helpful outcome for an off-topic flag on the basis that it is asking for a recommendation.

EDIT 2

The question was subsequently put on hold as being off-topic because it was asking for a recommendation and has now been deleted. It would be fairer if all flags recognising this were marked as helpful.

Comment: If I remember correctly, when a flag is disputed, it means something in the line of "the flag isn't relevant anymore" (mostly because the problem was taken care of already).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag

Comment: The flag was disputed because [triage said the post looks okay](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21247037).  Fortunately in this case the post has attracted close votes, and so is in the close vote queue despite triage (once again) doing it wrong, so the only actual effect is your flag status (which doesn't really matter as long as you know you were right), and it has no effect on what actually happens to that question.

Comment: @Servy. My contribution to the review is not shown on the link, but I flagged to close for the reason the question has now been put on hold. Is this a bug?

Comment: *My question is how can a question that is overtly asking for a recommendation not result in a helpful outcome...* The triage reviewers either weren't paying attention, don't actually know the rules for the site, or decided to keep it open despite the rule against it.

Comment: It's not a bug. It got close votes *after* the Triage review that disputed your flag.

Comment: @BSMP. Thank you for your explanation.  Much more use than spurious duplicate flags!

Comment: @Nick The triage review doesn't show all people that performed moderation actions on the post, it just lists the people that specifically used the Triage queue to triage that post, and what those people did from that review queue.  There are no software bugs here at all, just people misbehaving.

Comment: @Servy. Thank you. I think I saw it on the Triage queue too. I have only looked at questions with a specific tag tonight.

Comment: [This question is being discussed, er, here...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375825/1079354)